# Facebook feed on website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to display Facebook feeds of the user who logged in to my site using FB login. FB feed will be displayed in their profile page.

I saw that this feature is only available for limited number of selected media publishers. Link - [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed)

Is that so or can we actually do this?

Comment: Public Feed API is for _searching_ information among all public posts. A user’s feed you would get with `/userid/feed`. `read_stream` is the permission to read the full feed, including posts by others – but that you will most likely not get granted in review. To get the user’s own posts, you can use `user_posts` permission.

Comment: @CBroe Damn, you're faster at writing.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds impossible, because Facebook doesn't grant the `read_stream` permission anymore.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed/

You could, if you're fine with just the user's own posts, use the `user_posts` permission:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_posts

Comment: Thanks @Tobi . I read all these articles and understood that. But I just wanted to confirm. Thanks again